Is there any reason to believe Temu goods are more likely to involve slavery than the equivalent goods from other retailers?
There are questions about the use of forced labour in the supply chain of consumer goods.  One particular company that have been highlighted as a risk is the Chinese retailer Temu, with a Congressional report
in 2023 finding:

American consumers should know that there is an extremely high risk that Temu’s supply chains are contaminated with forced labor
As part of the probe, the committee sent letters in early May to brands Nike and Adidas, as well as Shein and Temu asking for information about their compliance with the anti-forced labor law.

It seems to me that big name brands that command significant loyalty and premium prices like Nike and Adidas are almost the "opposite" of the no name very cheap consumer goods that Temu specialises in.  I would have thought a more reasonable comparison would be the suppliers of small consumer goods to Walmart (in the US), Wilko (in the UK) and Amazon and those who use its marketplace.
Is there any evidence that the cheapest example of a consumer good, such as a knife, a belt or reading glasses, purchased from Temu would have a higher probability of being made with forced labour than the cheapest such good purchased from a more traditional retailer in the West?

There are a few attempts to rank how companies perform, such as the CCLA Modern Slavery Benchmark in the UK which ranks Kingfisher (B&Q, Screwfix, etc), Marks & Spencer, Next, Tesco, Reckitt Benckiser, and Unilever in the highest tier and e.g. Sainsbury's, Coca-Cola, and Ocado lower. But Temu isn't in the list.

I think the nutshell would be profit-maximization mostly subject to Chinese laws vs the same mostly subject to US or other Western countries' laws. The US of course declares signficant portions of China as doing forced-labor https://www.dol.gov/agencies/ilab/against-their-will-the-situation-in-xinjiang

BTW, much of the EU hasn't exactly been in a hurry to follow the US designations/laws in re Xianjing. https://www.politico.eu/article/china-forced-labor-ban-europe-us-uyghur-xinjiang/

Based on all the circumstances, I think it's reasonable to assume the risk of involvement of forced labour is higher with Temu than with Nike or Adidas. This isn't a claim that the latter represent no risk, it's a claim they represent less risk than Temu.

Temu's business model involves shipments that are exempt (the so-called de minimis exception) from inspections, duties and data provision to Customs and Border Protection (CBP),  to which higher value shipments would be subject (i.e. shipments over $800 - Nike and Adidas shipments are well in excess of $800).

According to the committee's interim report (Select Committee Releases Interim Findings from Shein & Temu Forced Labor Investigation), Temu didn't claim to have "any compliance or auditing system to independently verify that the tens of thousands of sellers who list on Temu are not selling products produced with Uyghur forced labor."


The likes of Nike and Adidas claim to conduct inspections (announced and unannounced) of their supply chains, they claim to have supplier contracts that prohibit sourcing  anything (yarns, textiles, goods) from Xinjiang, they report their compliance issues in their annual reports, etc etc, and they likely have evidence for these claims. Again, none of this is to claim they are perfect, it is a claim they are (a) claiming to care (again, Temu doesn't) and (b) they can provide some evidence of making some effort (Temu can't/won't).

Temu itself admitted it "does not expressly prohibit third-party sellers from selling products based on their origin in the Xinjiang Autonomous Region". Temu does not prohibit the sale of products that explicitly advertise their Xinjiang origins. Temu's website listed at least one product purported to be made from "Xinjiang Cotton". In US law - the Uyghur Forced Labor Prevention Act or UFLPA - there is a rebuttable presumption that such goods are made by forced labour, i.e. the importer must prove they were not made by forced labour.

As Temu is not the importer of record with respect to goods shipped to the United States, the laws against importing goods made with forced labour do not apply to it, they apply to the individual person (who isn't having their import inspected, because it's de minimis, or doing other compliance given they are just an ordinary member of the public, not a company). As Nike and Adidas are the importers of record for their goods, they are subject to the laws pertaining to the products of forced labour.


So the one hand you've got a business that isn't even claiming to care to prevent forced labour, it's not subject to US law pertaining to the products of forced labour, its shipments are exempt from scrutiny by CBP, it does sell products sourced from Xinjiang.
On the other hand you've got a business that is at least claiming to care (and to some extent can back this up), it's subject to US law (and European and UK law, I'll add) pertaining to the products of forced labour, its shipments are subject to scrutiny by CBP, and at least appears to make an effort to avoid using anything sourced from Xinjiang.

Someone has commented that "This answer is based exclusively on faith and racism."
Wrong. My answer is not racist, it is business-ist.
I don't assume USA=good and China=bad. I haven't written or indicated anything of the sort here.
I assume that (big) businesses anywhere will often do wrong - or don't care if wrong is done - if they can profit. I assume they are often amoral profit-seekers.
A shocking assumption, I know, but there is plenty of precedent everywhere. As a consequence, many if not all legal jurisdictions have developed myriad regulations on business.
Those regulations create different (dis)incentives depending on jurisdiction and business model.
Nike and Temu are exposed to different (dis)incentives.

Good write up, but please note that, historically, Nike pretty much kickstarted the move for aggressive audits of multinationals' supply chains with its 1991 child labor scandal https://www.newidea.com.au/real-life/nike-sweatshops-the-truth-about-the-nike-factory-scandal/.  Which might very well make them a lot more compliant, nowadays, true.

This is a good answer. It clearly explains the multiple points of the Temu business model visa vie Temu itself and its many suppliers. Most of the suppliers are small and unmonitored as described. The difference is between a few large monitored companies and a quagmire of smaller unmonitored companies that have no consequence if / when they are caught.


American consumers should know that there is an extremely high risk that Temu’s supply chains are contaminated with forced labor

This is technically true but ignores the realities of the Xinjiang economy. As per China's stats of GDP output per administrative region, Xinjiang as a whole is only 1.5% of its total economy. Which makes sense as they're only 1.7% of the total Chinese population. The share of goods on Temu sold from Xinjiang as a whole could thus be reasonably presumed to be 1.5% or less.
Once you correct for the fact that heavy industry is much more concentrated on the east coast of China and the fact that not 100% of Xinjiang's goods are made with slave labor, I'd be very surprised if more than 0.5% of the total value of goods sold on Temu had slave labor involved. So, yes, its plausible that some good had slave labor involved at some point in their manufacturing process but it's a bit hyperbolic to associate Temu as a whole with slave camps.

Just from a maths point, if 1% of the 1.7% was slave picked cotton which was found in all cotton clothes much more than 1% of goods would have slave labour involved.

@User65535 it’s about the total % of revenue of Temu driven by Xinjiang slave labor, not trace quantities of cotton in every single clothes item.

The operant principle in capitalist production is to maximize profit. This implies that companies are balancing material costs, labor costs, 'risk' factors, and sale price to achieve the most favorable outcome. Given the complexities of modern production chains, companies may not know — or may choose not to look too closely — at the nature of labor being used by remote contractors. This applies to expensive goods and cheap goods, and to 'status' goods and 'basic' goods.
As a point of reference, many years ago Nike — I think when they were in the early stages of marketing high-end Air Jordan athletic shoes — paid Michael Jordan a fee for his sponsorship that was greater than the combined yearly salaries of all the East Asian workers who made those Air Jordans. I'm not suggesting that any of those workers were enslaved, mind you; I'm pointing out that this is the way the system works.
The only 'risk' factors in modern production chains are:

legal liability for improper acts
bad publicity from questionable or amoral acts
marketing failures that result in excessive unsold commodities

(3) is negligible because because of the marketing focus of both major and minor brands. Pay the Jordans of the world enough, and you'll sell shoes. (1) is negligible because of varying laws between jurisdiction. If people in Shanghai or Mumbai (not to mention prisoners in US States like Louisiana or Georgia) are forced to work, it isn't illegal, so there's no legal risk of lawsuit to the corporate bottom line. (2) is the only real financial risk, and it's generally resolved by cut-outs: CEOs and stock holders will assert that they have 'no idea' that subcontractors are using immoral labor practices, while simultaneously seeking out subcontractors with the lowest unit prices.
Temu is no better (and no worse) in this regard than (say) Amazon, and likely no worse than a typical corporate brick-and-mortar department store. They all want to buy cheap and sell dear, and are not too interested in examining the practices of those who sell them goods on the cheap.

+1 One of the reasons nobody has been able to wrestle the virtual monopoly on chip manufacturing that Taiwan has it's because you can't do it without replicating the appalling conditions their workers have. Which means that prestigious brand markets such as Apple, nVidia or Intel are basically running sweatshops in South-Eastern Asia.

This is pure speculation and doesn't answer the question. There are laws such as modern slavery laws in the UK and EU, and pressure from ethical investment firms, so some firms do attempt some kind of audit trail. Some companies put more effort in than others, and there's no clue where Temu lies on the scale.

While an argument can perhaps be made that [US-side] prison-labor or even cheap-labor isn't that different from China's way of employing the Uyghurs (and surely Nike etc. have been accused of the former https://www.business-humanrights.org/en/latest-news/prison-blues-starbucks-nike-others-profit-from-inmate-labor-at-us-prisons/), Temu suremly cares more about Chinese law, and less about the US one. IMHO this answer is putting up too much of a smoke screen in front of that with too much generic talk of profit maximization etc.

"Temu is no better (and no worse) in this regard than (say) Amazon." Well, that's exactly what is being asked, isn't it? I don't think most people are suggesting that, for instance, Jeff Bezos is actually a more moral person than Lei Chen, but rather whether there is anything in their business models or the markets or legal frameworks that they operate in that makes the latter's company more likely to use enslaved workers.

@Rekesoft - I'm not sure how plausible that is as a major factor. Taiwan has major issues with exploitation of workers—but a lot of the most-exploited workers in Taiwan are from other parts of Asia, no doubt because employers can get away with paying them less than Taiwan's 760 euro/month minimum wage (Thailand, Cambodia, and Vietnam are closer to 200 to 300). But it would be even easier to just produce products in one of those three countries, which also have loose worker protections, if not for the fact that Taiwan has most of the extremely expensive chip-printing machines.

@Rekesoft You have to bring some stronger sources to the table on this claim.  With fabs nearing the $10B per plant, doubt that is a major reason.  FWIW, one of the reasons TSMC is struggling opening their plants in the US is lack of qualified workers - fab work is not sweatshop work and their workers are not interchangeable low-skill workers.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: I'm content with the downvotes. I'm debating whether to delete the answer.

I don't really lean one way or another on your answer, which I did not vote on.  Just on Rekesoft's claim, which looks very sketchy and dogmatic in its reasoning.  Just like calling out the other A for racism which was also over the top.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Don't forget their 'reductio ad israelum' where they compare corporations to the Israeli Defense Forces. Because, of course, there is some useful analogy between Israeli massacres that have killed tens of thousands of people in less than a year and American or Chinese companies that may have forced labor in their supply chain that promotes understanding of the latter issue, right?
